# Cannot boot system due to start job running for hold

Tags: boot, 16.04

I've installed ubuntu-desktop on Ubuntu 16.04 Gnome and I picked lightdm and now once I restart, I get this error message when I press CTRL + ALT + F2:

```
A start job is running for Hold until boot process finishes up (Xmin Xs/no limit)
```

This goes on for 20 minutes+. What do I do to fix this problem or even troubleshoot?

Comment: FYI after upgrade left mine running overnight - so 10+ hours same issue.

Comment: My ubuntu 17.04 has the same error just now, ctrl+shit+N change tty, login, reboot, no more error. Not sure it will happen again in future or not though.

Comment: A possible fox for a similar-sounding issue on Ubuntu 17 can be found at https://askubuntu.com/a/1007917/156671.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You can fix this in following way, it worked for me.
**FYI :** I had upgraded from 14.04 to 16.04.

Go in your safe mode by hitting **SHIFT** key or **ESC**.
select **networking** , then drop to **root prompt**. Then run following commands.

```
sudo apt-get remove plymouth
sudo apt-get remove xserver-xorg-video-intel
```

Now, reboot,

When you reboot, still you may get black or purple screen,

Press `Ctrl+Alt+F1` and login with your username and password.

Then run following commands.

GDM ie Gnome display manager was also causing problems for me, so following step was essential for me

I switched to lightdm from gdm3  as display manager.

```
sudo apt-get install lightdm
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

When you are prompted, select default display manager as **lightdm**

Now I was back with desktop , **without dash or unity** but only icons and wallpaper.
now run this.

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

Now, **reboot** after this.

The desktop is back!

now, you can install intel graphic drivers again,

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-intel
```

**Reboot now**.
Its done!

Comment: The great penguin god bless you, awesome human. You saved me.

Comment: Upgraded from 15.10 to 16.04 because of libcogl and/or Nvidia issues, same problem. Removing plymouth and lightdm did it for me.

Comment: I didn't need to uninstall plymouth to fix the issue (and I was getting a scary prompt concerning cryptsetup doing so in the root shell). Switching to lightdm helped, yet I was getting stuck in a login loop. [To fix it I had to chown `.Xauthority`](http://askubuntu.com/a/223634/32792)

Comment: I got errors saying the file system was mounted read-only (even in recovery???) so I had to do this: `mount -o rw,remount /`

Comment: At the end, my session was opening then closed immediately: i had to do this:     chown myusername /home/myusername/.Xauthority

Comment: @swapyonubuntu - Thanks. This solution worked for me!

Comment: Thabks very much

Comment: Thanks swapyonubuntu! 1) hit and hold shift after bios is done to get grub. 2) Chose Advanced options. 3) Chose Ubuntu, ..., (recovery mode). Grey options screen. 4) Chose "network". I was only on wifi so may not do anything. Brought Back to grey options screen.  5) Chose drop to root. 6) Press Enter. Gets root prompt (#). lightdm was already installed so I just ran the command 7) sudo dpgk-reconfigure lightdm. Ctl-Alt-Del and had full unity desktop back.

Comment: wow, i must remember never to select gdm.

Comment: I also had a problem with `upstart-udev-bridge`.  As suggested at http://askubuntu.com/questions/763735/ubuntu-16-04-blank-screen-at-bootup, running `cat ~/.xsession-errors` led me to realise that I needed to add `/sbin` to my PATH

Comment: You are, as my primary school librarian used to say, a legend in your own electric lunchbox!

Comment: I followed this solution and the problem was fixed right after removing xserver-xorg-video-intel package, I followed instructions still nonetheless and when I reinstall the said package back, i got a bad visual glitch (the login was fine, I was on desktop, but distorted). So I again removed 'xserver-xorg-video-intel' and now it seems to work. Running Ubuntu 18.04 from VirtualBox

Answer (score 9):

Had the same problem earlier today.

Found out here (https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=195223) that could be a plymouth related problem, and after removing it (I'm really not into looping logins animations anyway...), I got into trouble with nvidia drivers.

I just removed all nvidia related software and, voilà, I'm here typing this answer.

```
sudo apt-get remove plymouth
sudo apt-get purge nvidia
sudo reboot
```

Comment: Had the same problem and this worked for me. Thanks

Comment: Actually, I fixed my issue. I just did `sudo apt-get purge nvidia-common` and that fixed the problem.

Answer (score 6):

For those who messed up with Linux booting after the update (Which happened to many users including me) Here's the complete solution (Which I used, and I was able to get back everything).

1. **Don't panic!**
2. If your computer is hanged at the login screen, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>f2</kbd>
3. It will ask for your login username and password.
4. Connect ethernet cable (LAN cable) from your wifi router or modem to your computer
5. Type `dhclient eth0` and press <kbd>enter</kbd>
6. For testing networking, try `ping www.google.com` if there's any failure then please check your LAN connection, router or modem (Connecting to WiFi is a tedious process so try LAN connection first)
7. Type `reboot` and press <kbd>enter</kbd>.
8. Now keep pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd> key.
9. Enter into latest kernel recovery mode.
10. Use keyboard arrow keys to navigate.
11. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> on `Networking`
12. Now it will display the previous screen.
13. Click on root (You need root access to modify system).
14. Run

    ```
    sudo apt-get install -f --reinstall lightdm
    ```

    (It will download 200mb of data)
15. Run

    ```
    sudo apt-get install unity
    ```
16. Run

    ```
    sudo apt-get install ubuntu-session
    ```
17. Run

    ```
    sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
    ```
18. It will ask you to select one out of two options: `gdm` & `lightdm`. Select `lightdm`
19. Run

    ```
    sudo apt-get install gnome
    ```

    ( It will download 700mb of data)
20. Run `reboot` and you should be able to get your work back (Although your desktop will look ugly because of conflicting themes. Don't worry, steps 23 & 24 will fix this issue).
21. Open terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and run

    ```
    sudo apt-get autoremove
    ```

    (to purge all unnecessary dependencies which can cause problems while installing new packages)
22. Run

    ```
    sudo apt install unity-tweak-tool
    ```
23. Run

    ```
    sudo apt-get autoremove --purge light-themes
    ```
24. Run

    ```
    sudo apt-get install light-themes
    ```
25. Finally download ubuntu-tweak from [ubuntuupdates.com](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/ubuntu-tweak) (version that works with Xenial Xerus and isn't available anywhere else!)
26. Reboot your system and done!

Comment: Big round of applause! Saved my day!

Comment: This did NOT fix the theme conflict problem. The icons are conflicted, when I drag e.g. terminal, it doesn't drag in real time (imagine dragging folders in windows XP), etc. Can anyone help?

Comment: if it hangs during boot (e.g. `Failed to start Login Service`), control+alt+f2 won't show an usable tty though...

Comment: @FlorianCastellane it should work but if it is not working you may check function keys in your boot menu if they need 'fn+f2' or just 'f2'

Comment: that's not for entering the boot menu, that's for accessing tty2

Comment: @FlorianCastellane, control+alt+f2 isnt working for you to enter tty, so I suggest you to try control+atl+fn+f2 Depending on hardware, some require fn(function key)+f2 to make 'f2' work. That is why I suggesyed you to look into boot menu whether you need fn+f2 or just f2.

Comment: yes it does work. what I meant is that I would not get a login prompt at tty2.

Comment: Step 3 can just be reboot, it solved the issue for me

Answer (score 3):

I just had the same issue on a fresh Ubuntu 19.04 on a ThinkPad X201. The system would hang forever with a black screen and not react to any keyboard input. At next reboot (into recovery mode) when examining `/var/log/boot.log` I would see the error told in the question:

```
A start job is running for Hold until boot process finishes up (Xmin Xs/no limit)
```

Funny enough, I was able to start in recovery mode until I see the recovery mode menu and, from there, when choosing "resume" I would get to the normal graphical environment. The difference to a normal mode was only that the boot process was done in text mode. This indicates that there is a conflict between the display manager and `plymouth`, the software responsible for showing the graphical screen with the Ubuntu logo etc. while the computer boots up.

And indeed, the only step required to fix this was removing `plymouth`, by executing in recovery mode:

```
sudo apt remove plymouth
```

And rebooting.

Comment: This worked for me. Had the exact same solution.

Comment: Thanks, that solved my problem too .. However the animated Ubuntu logo disappeared. But who cares!

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same problem after installing the Nvidia driver (361).  I removed it and its all working okay now. I have a GeForce 920 (Optimus). Nouveau works fine with it, so I shall stick with it for a few more months and try installing the Nvidia driver again (hoping the bug will have beebln fixed by then).

Answer (score 0):

You can skip the wait and go to your log-in screen directly by using '<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>+</kbd><kbd>c</kbd>' and then work on the solution. Sometimes this will go on forever if not.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to download the `mini.iso` version of the installer; it bypasses the problem. Be sure to have a good internet access when you install it, it will download a lot of files.

During the setup, you will be asked which kind of Ubuntu to install.