# Blank screen at boot - errors from Upstart on 16.04

Tags: boot, upstart

When I boot up, I see the x-windows where I can enter my login, then it gives me a blank desktop background where I see a mouse pointer and nothing else. I can switch to a TTY.

I get these errors on Ubuntu 15.10 and 16.04

```
$ cat ~/.xsession-errors
openConnection: connect: No such file or directory
cannot connect to brltty at :0
upstart: Failed to spawn upstart-udev-bridge main process: unable to execute: No such file or directory
upstart: unity-gtk-module pre-start process (1418) terminated with status 127
upstart: dbus pre-start process (1425) terminated with status 127
```

Any suggestions on what I could do?

Comment: this could also be related but does not appear to give a solution - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-greeter/+bug/1537616

Comment: I had altered my `/etc/environment` file and had this issue. The problem was that the `PATH` variable no longer could see the `upstart-udev-bridge` command because it is in`/sbin`. Replacing the line: `PATH=$PATH:/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin` at the top of that file fixed my issue.

Answer (score 3):

I had altered my `/etc/environment` file and had this issue. The problem was that the `PATH` variable no longer could see the `upstart-udev-bridge` command because it is in`/sbin`. Replacing the line: `PATH=$PATH:/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin` at the top of that file fixed my issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. But it vanished once I did the following:

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to get to command line login.
2. Log in using user account you have setup during installation.
3. `sudo apt-get update` followed by 
   `sudo apt-get upgrade`
4. `reboot`. When I logged in again, it worked.

Turns out many packages including upstart get upgraded with the bug fixed.

Hope this helps others.