# Is cryptsetup required to unlock fully encrypted disk?

Tags: 16.04, encryption, plymouth, cryptsetup

I was [running into an issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760825/cannot-boot-system-due-to-start-job-running-for-hold) after upgrading from 14.04 to 16.04.

Following an answer, I ran in the root shell:

```
apt-get remove plymouth
```

Yet `cryptsetup` requires `plymouth` and it would have been unitalled as well, which is why I got a scary notice:

> This system has unlocked dm-crypt devices: sda5_crypt
>
> If these devices are managed with cryptsetup, you might be unable to
>   lock the devices after the package removal, though other tools can be
>   used for managing dm-crypt devices. Any system shutdown or reboot will
>   lock the devices.
>
> Do not choose this option if you want to lock the dm-crypt devices
>   before package removal.
>
> Continue with cryptsetup removal?

I hit "no", yet it was still uninstalled.

So I quickly re-installed plymouth

```
apt-get install plymouth
```

praying that I still could unlock my disk after reboot, which I could. (And it turns out removing `plymouth` wasn't needed to fix my problem.)

Yet I am having trouble understanding the meaning of the prompt.

- Could I have safely uninstalled plymouth and still access my fully encrypted disk on boot?
- How is locking the device a bad/good thing?
- What would have happened on reboot if I had kept it uinstalled?
- What would have hitting `yes` have done?

What exactly is the point of the message?