# Restore Ubuntu 16.04 Login Screen

Tags: lightdm, login-screen, kylin

I installed Ubuntu Kylin Theme but I want to restore the original login in screen for ubuntu, I tried to uninstall the theme, purge and reinstall the lightdm and also change the default to gdm with `dpkg-reconfigure` but I always get the Ubuntu Kylin login screen.

**EDIT:**

I tried to see the configuration in Ubuntu Tweak but only show the default login screen configuration even showing Ubuntu Kylin when I boot the computer.

[image: screenshot of Ubuntu Tweak tool]

Comment: In my tries I also get a black screen and have to uninstall plymouth and reinstall lightdm and ubuntu-desktop like the answer in this [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/760825/cannot-boot-system-due-to-start-job-running-for-hold) but after that i still get ubuntu kylin on login screen

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`kylin-greeter` is a version of LightDM greeter, and to switch back to the default greeter ( which is `unity-greeter` ) one must tell lightdm which one to use via configuration file.

What you want to do is edit ( or create if it doesn't exist ) the file `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`

Basic steps ( done from terminal )

1. Open the file with your text editor. You can use `nano` because it's easier. `sudo nano /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`
2. If you have `[SeatDefaults]` line, go to step 3. Otherwise, add this line.
3. Bellow `[SeatDefaults]` add `greeter-session=unity-greeter` line.
4. Save with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>. Exit with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> .
5. Reboot, or go into TTY1 ( via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> ） ， login there and restart lightdm with `sudo service lightdm restart`

Comment: Sergiy, is that a typo when you say in step 2 "If you don't have..."? Should it be "If you have...".
Very useful answer btw, thanks.

Comment: @gmagno Yep.  Already fixed. Glad you found it useful :)

Comment: Sergiy feel free to share some love and upvote my comment if you found it useful ;)