# 16.04 & 16.10 - Login Screen Locks, cannot login as another user until I logout

Tags: login

This quirk has been bugging me, and especially my non-techy partner. If either of us allows the system to auto-lock the system due to inactivity. We cannot access the dropdown to login as ourselves, we have to log back in as the original(last) user, log out then login as ourselves, then log in again as if we had locked the system.

Just to recap, because maybe it's not obvious.

'A' logs in and the system auto-locks due to inactivity.
'B' is able to log in and does so, system auto-locks due to inactivity.
'A' is unable to log in now. 'A' logs into system as 'B', logs 'B' out, then logs in as 'A', gets to the original login screen and eventually logs in as 'A'

phew...!

Comment: Did you try clicking the top right gear icon and selecting the user you wish to login as? Also, you use a different display manager to login (ie: GDM).

Comment: Yes the gear at the top right is non-functional. All functions date/time, keyboard, gear etc. grey out and do nothing. I am using the standard display manager, shipping with Ubuntu

Comment: I would try installing GDM then- "sudo apt-get install gdm", "sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm", restart.

Comment: @PatrickNegus ... that caused some issues! unable to boot up system, had to go to safe mode and follow: http://askubuntu.com/questions/760825/cannot-boot-system-due-to-start-job-running-for-hold to get it back... not sure where GDM borked everything but think I'll have to reconsider this option.

Comment: Oh no, sorry!.. *sits in corner and cries*

Comment: It's ok, we all live another day!

Answer (score 2):

There are rare occasions where an application or screen savor might not show the regular screen.  When this happens there are two ways the two of you can log in.  One way is using either the Gear icon at on the top right hand of the screen or scrolling to the name on the Login screen.

An alternate way (**Method #2**) is to switch to the users DISPLAY.  The GUI displays start with `F7` and move up as needed... `F8`, `F9`, etc.  You can change displays by holding down the <kbd>Cntrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> and hitting the <kbd>F#</kbd> key of the display you want.  You will see the user's name as the login option of his display.

Comment: Thanks for this, used ubuntu for years and never knew the CTRL+ALT+F# would give me the other users desktop.

Comment: You're welcome.  Glad it worked!