# Upgrade 16.10 problem: only background and pointer after login

Tags: ubuntu-gnome, 16.10, xserver, display-manager

Definition:

After upgrading from 16.04 to 16.10, the Ubuntu login show the background and the pointer. No Dash, no Launcher, no access to keyboard, cannot summon the terminal (ctrl+alt+t or ctrl+F2). 
If I select the Unity8 session same thing. 
If I select the GNOME, it works fine after turning the screen black for a second.

Diagnostic:

Same problem was described by people upgrading to 16.04

[Problems after upgrading to 14.04 (only background and pointer after login)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/449845/problems-after-upgrading-to-14-04-only-background-and-pointer-after-login/481620#481620)

and

[Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears)

But all the solutions given does not works for me (mainly --reinstall ubuntu-desktop).
This seems to be related to a nvidia graphic card and driver problem that I am indeed running (nvs5100M, driver 340.98).

Getting worst before getting better:

I try to change the display manager from lightdm to gdm3:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

Bad decision: I had a black screen instead of the login.
ctrl+F1 gave me an error message:

> "A start job is running for Hold until boot process finishes up"

I followed the instruction from this link:

[Cannot boot system due to start job running for hold](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760825/cannot-boot-system-due-to-start-job-running-for-hold)

After restart, the Ubuntu session is now working fine.
I have no clue why, but you guys better figure that out because it is horrible and I lost 6 hours today trying to fix this $hit!

Seriously, that might help other people.