# Stuck at Kubuntu splash screen after adding Kde to Ubuntu

Tags: unity, kde, login-screen

Hello I seem to be stuck on the kubuntu splash screen after I installed both Kubuntu-Desktop and Gnome-shell on my Ubuntu 16.10 install.

Comment: Can you go in the Grub menu when booting ? After starting your computer, hold down the shift key to make the Grub menu appear. Then press the "e" of edit when the default kernel line is visible. After that find the line with "splash quiet", and remove both those words, and continue booting. See the help commands at the bottom of the Grub menu. This would enable you to see more details at which point your boot up would stall.

Comment: See also this nice posting for some more visual help on the Grub menu part : https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it

Comment: yep i do have access to the grub boot menu im dual booting windows, ill try that thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get past the splash with albert's help found this:

`A start job is running for Hold until boot process finishes up (Xmin Xs/no limit)`

[This answer][1] seemed like it could be my problem and reconfiguring `lightdm` did fix it . by bringing up the terminal with alt right arrow.

[1] [Cannot boot system due to start job running for hold](https://askubuntu.com/q/760825/645195)