# A start job is running for hold until boot process finishes up and can not connect to network niether WiFi or LAN

Tags: boot, networking, gnome-terminal, lightdm, 16.10

I have ubuntu 16.10 and i've installed ubuntu-desktop on ubuntu 16.10 Gnome and i picked lightdm and i restart it and when i press `Ctrl + Alt + F2` it shows `A start job is running for hold until boot process finishes up (Xmin Xs/no limit)` I have wait until 40 minutes.

After this i search this problem, I found some methods like go into ***recovery mode*** or select ***Networking*** and after ***drop to root prompt*** and run command like

```
sudo apt-get remove plymouth
sudo apt-get remove xserver-xorg-video-intel
sudo apt-get install lightdm
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

reboot and you desktop will back and install graphic driver back or I've try

```
sudo apt-get install -f --reinstall lightdm 
sudo apt-get install unity
```

or some few command more but there is no internet so i can use `sudo apt-get` command for download or install lightdm back i  have tried all command **without login** or **with login** on ***drop to root prompt***

I have tried solution of this question [cannot boot system due to start job running for hold](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760825/cannot-boot-system-due-to-start-job-running-for-hold)
still no effect and ***give solution of how to connect WiFi or LAN when i was in drop to root prompt there `ifconfig` give the LAN cable connection but i can not use it's internet*** please help me to solve this problem

Comment: Do you know how to drop to advanced options in grub menu?