# Ubuntu 16.04 stuck in login loop (seriously)

Tags: apt, updates, login, crash

I found alot of questions with the same title put it all can't help.

My os :
Ubuntu 16.04 LTS amd64 (xenial)

My kernel :
4.12.0-041200 kernel

My ~/.xsession-errors :

```
openConnection: connect: No such file or directory
cannot connect to brltty at :0
upstart: gnome-session (GNOME) main process (1603) terminated with status 1
upstart: logrotate main process (1449) killed by TERM signal
upstart: update-notifier-crash (/var/crash/libglapi-mesa.0.crash) main process (1504) killed by TERM signal
upstart: update-notifier-crash (/var/crash/libsdl2-2.0-0.0.crash) main process (1505) killed by TERM signal
upstart: update-notifier-crash (/var/crash/libvdpau1.0.crash) main process (1506) killed by TERM signal
upstart: bamfdaemon main process (1556) killed by TERM signal
upstart: Disconnected from notified D-Bus bus
```

and All my pakages is upgraded

Please help me with this

update : what caused the problem ?

I have tried to replace libglapi-mesa new verion with an old one, and the package dependencies did't match with the package version and i have removed sources.list file and removed the main packages then followed this [Cannot boot system due to start job running for hold](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760825/cannot-boot-system-due-to-start-job-running-for-hold) then this problem happend

Comment: Does it work if you use the correct kernel for your version of Ubuntu?

Comment: ^ and when did this start to happen? What did you try and what happened?

Comment: I have tried to replace libglapi-mesa new verion with an old one, and the package dependencies did't match  with the package version and i have removed sources.list file and removed the main packages then followed this (cannot boot system due to start job running for hold) https://askubuntu.com/questions/760825/cannot-boot-system-due-to-start-job-running-for-hold rhen this problem happend.

Comment: (Doug smythies) how to do that

Comment: I never saw your comment. If you want to alert me use # as the first character, then the name. Anyway, I see you started [a new question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/950308/how-to-reset-all-kernel-changes), which I am linking here so that I can find it again later.

Comment: #Doug Smyrhies i had installed the best kernel for my version 4.4.0-92 and the still occurs

Comment: i have reinstalled ubuntu and the problem solved :) thank you for all your hard work.