# How can I reinstall the default Ubuntu 16.04 kernel after installing a newer kernel and deleting all the others?

Tags: software-installation, kernel

- Version :Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
- Kernel version : 4.12.0-041200-lowtency

How can I roll back to the default (original) and correct kernel for my Ubuntu version? I installed a newer kernel and deleted all the other kernels from `/boot`. I installed the new kernel manually and without installing HWE.

When I run `sudo apt update && sudo apt full upgrade`, it doesn't download any kernels, just the usual `sources.list` file check and finally it says (0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded`.

How can I install the default Ubuntu kernel for my system?

Comment: did you delete all the other kernels? have you made changes to APT? How did you install the 4.12 kernel

Comment: Yes i did it to free some space to my /boot

Comment: If you run `sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade`, does it install any kernels? Please could you [edit] your question to add more information?

Comment: OK, thanks for the update. Could you please try to install the current 16.04 kernel explicitly using the command `sudo apt install linux-image-4.4.0-92-generic`. Could you also tell us how you deleted the other kernels you had installed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed this by installing the current 16.04 kernel explicitly with the command

```
sudo apt install linux-image-4.4.0-92-generic
```