# Ubuntu 17.10: "a start job is running for Hold until boot process finishes up (time/no limit)

Tags: startup

Installed 17.10 about a month ago, havn't had any issues until today after my windows machine decided to restart itself automatically. Upon logging back into Virtual box and Ubuntu I get this error. Has me puzzled. I'm a noob, so I thought it was operator error, but it may not be. Any resources or ideas are appreciated!

My host is windows, using virtual box for Ubuntu 17.10

Comment: Sorry, yeah, my host computer is windows, and Ubuntu is loaded through virtual box.

Comment: Does the login come to completion?  I mean, are you able to start a terminal and run `systemd-analyze critical-chain`?

Comment: no, it does it during the start up

Comment: If the start job indeed never finishes, then I reckon your only help would be a rollback of a  snapshot of  a working state of your VM. If you don't have a snapshot then I think your VM is a goner. To at least retrieve your files, build a second VM and add the disk of the first to it.

Comment: Thank you, I was afraid you were going to say that. I thought I had saved it, but apparently not. I built up a fresh machine this afternoon just in case. sigh.

Comment: Sorry you had to find out the hard way why the snapshot option is so highlighted in the docs of all VM software vendors.

Comment: For posterity, once it locks up, I hit alt-f2, and able to login that way command line. So it's there, I just can't see the desktop.

Comment: Ah ok. So all is not lost then.  You have a choice to make now: 1) You could try and find out what part of the desktop is damaged (time consuming). 2) Remove/re-install the desktop; hoping that repairs it. 3) install and switch to another desktop, f.e. xfce4. As you have already built a fresh VM, I can imagine you don't bother and concentrate on regularly making snapshots  ;-)

Answer (score 2):

This can be caused from a broken version of Guest Additions. From https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads :

> Important: The Guest Additions which come with VirtualBox 5.2.6 and
>   5.1.32 do not work properly on Linux guests with 3D enabled. Here are updated versions for [5.2.6](https://www.virtualbox.org/download/testcase/VBoxGuestAdditions_5.2.7-120528.iso) and [5.1.32](https://www.virtualbox.org/download/testcase/VBoxGuestAdditions_5.1.33-120529.iso).

The easiest way to fix the issue seems to be:

1. Power down the VM
2. Disable 3D Acceleration in VirtualBox Disaply Settings
3. Boot the system and install the updated Guest Additions
4. Power down the VM
5. Re-enable 3D Acceleration in VirtualBox Disaply Settings
6. Power up the VM system, which now boots correctly