# 18.04 Boot freezes at "Started Hold until boot process finishes up"

Tags: boot, reboot

I have been encountering some trouble trying to boot 18.04. When I attempt to boot it becomes stuck "Started Hold until boot process finishes up", and ctrl+alt+f1/f2have no effect Following some instructions from the web I have tried booting into recovery mode to run networking and the execute some commands in the root shell. When I run network it freezes at "Flush Journal to Persistent Log". I have tried to fix that but I am quite new to Linux and have not been able to understand it. Any help is appreciated as I don't have the slightest idea of how to fix this. Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 15):

I had the exact same problem after a kernel upgrade. It turned out that my root partition was stuffed so much, it had no free space. I used the advanced mode menu to free up some space and restarted. It just worked afterwards.

Comment: Can you please tell how to enter advanced mode?

Comment: Select the "Advanced options for Ubuntu" item from the grub menu; it is usually located beneath the normal boot option. Then in order to free up some space, mount your root partition with write permission. Hope it helps.

Comment: I had to increase root partition size, advanced mode option did not free enough space.

Comment: Thanks.. so helpful, it works for me!!

Comment: follow this one :https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode  and than: `#df -h`, you can see that there is 0% dispo, you can remove some file from your `/home` or `/`, and than reboot, that s it !!

Answer (score 2):

The same issue happened, when there was no free space on the disk.

To clean up you may go to root terminal and clean any not needed files.
To do that you need while starting the system to press Shift(old systems) or Escape(new systems) button, then select booting in "recovery mode". Then select something like "root terminal". Clean up at least few G bytes. Type "exit" and choose option to "resume normal boot".

In any case, https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode should help you.

Answer (score 2):

I really don't know why it happens, but have worked around and came up with a solution with. The solution steps are

1. Change into tty. (!!!Yes you can change into tty)
2. Enter the credentials and change into root user using `sudo -s`.
3. Remove the Nvidia Driver which normally would have been there installed on your system. (I believe `apt-get remove --purge '^nvidia-.*'` will work as it is shown here [how-can-i-uninstall-a-nvidia-driver-completely](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206283/how-can-i-uninstall-a-nvidia-driver-completely)).
4. Remove `gdm`(Gnome-display-Manager) which is normally the display managers for gnome desktop environments using command `apt remove gdm`.
5. Re-install GDM using the command `apt install gdm`.
6. Reboot the system using the command `reboot`.
7. The above has to work and you would see the login screen again. Incase the above method works, you will need to re-install the Nvidia-drivers. I am sure there is a way you will work around it as it is completey graphical.

(SRY peeps, I myself am not an Ubuntu user, but have been long for 3 years. Have shifted to some other distro and faced the same issue and fixed it using the above steps. I believe it will work the same way for Ubuntu as well. Give it as try, maybe it works for you)

Answer (score -1):

I just entered the Ubuntu menu pressing ESC when booting, then choose Recovery Mode. It worked for me.

Comment: May you explain what you did after entering Recovery Mode? Also, what exactly did you get to work for you? Please elaborate.

Comment: Gordster I did absolutely nothing more than that. After choosing Recovery Mode the OS booted normally.