# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (dual booted with Windows 10) is stuck at "Started Hold until boot process finishes up"

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, disk-usage, recovery-mode

I think this issue might be because my root is almost completely full. The last time I successfully booted it up, I wasn't able to run certain applications (such as Google Chrome) and I'm guessing it is because of the same issue.

I freed up an extra ~5GB of space from my windows partition to add to the root filesystem but now I don't know how to add that extra 5GB to Ubuntu since it is no longer booting and I'm unable to use GParted.

When doing a normal boot, the system stops at "Started Hold until boot process finishes up", and I've tried clearing up space from the Advanced Menu (recovery mode) free option as well as tried deleting some files and folders from my desktop, downloads and such but the system is still not booting.

I went through the askUbuntu threads and looked for similar questions and I found [18.04 Boot freezes at "Started Hold until boot process finishes up"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1065094/18-04-boot-freezes-at-started-hold-until-boot-process-finishes-up) but it doesn't seem to cover how to fix this issue when the free option in the Advanced Menu doesn't actually free any space.

I would really like to fix this issue but if it is not fixable, I would like to overwrite the ubuntu partition(s) with my windows partition and get that space back. Is there any way to do this?

df -h output as I have been recommended to add here:

[Please see output here (Not enough reputation yet)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SceYy.jpg)

Thank you very much for your time and consideration.

Comment: Just about anything is fixable..if you have the skills. Are you essentially trying to say that you don't know what is safe to delete? Please edit your question to show the complete output of `df -h`.

Comment: More so than me not knowing what is safe to delete (which is true),  my question is more generally "What can I do here to fix this problem? Is this almost certainly a memory issue or something else I should consider".
Should I run the 'df -h' in recovery mode?

Answer (score 0):

Boot a live USB/recovery CD and run `gparted`, then while your Ubuntu partition is unmounted you can add the unallocated drive space to it. You should backup essential files and probably ~./config to your Windows partition, preferably even an external HDD, in case something goes wrong.

https://serverfault.com/questions/509468/how-to-extend-an-ext4-partition-and-filesystem

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowtoPartition