# Dual Boot Gone Wrong

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I need help with my dual boot. I have Windows 10 and Ubuntu running on my 256 GB SSD. The way I have my computer set up is on SSD I have my OS running with my games, while anything else downloaded on WINDOWS 10 will be downloaded to my 1 TB HDD. I tried doing it to Ubuntu one but couldn't manage it. Then something appeared telling me the storage that was meeting the maximum capacity. Then it just crash, and now every time I want to run Ubuntu this error appears. Thank you for your time and please help.

Here is a link to the picture for contexts. https://i.stack.imgur.com/aaZUu.jpg

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with dual booting it's user error, what you're seeing is just a normal boot without the 'Splash screen' and it doesn't actually show any errors, think of the boot sequence as a log for everything the OS does during boot, now, the last entry in this log is "started hold until boot process finishes up" a quick google search sends you to this question on askubuntu.com

[18.04 Boot freezes at "Started Hold until boot process finishes up"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1065094/18-04-boot-freezes-at-started-hold-until-boot-process-finishes-up)

tldr your root partition is filled up so the OS is unable to boot properly, details on how to fix it is in the link above.