# Boot fail after update: How to access encrypted home directory from root shell

Tags: updates, ecryptfs, recovery-mode

My Ubuntu 18.04 laptop has failed to boot up since an update yesterday evening.  I'm getting a "Started Hold until boot process finishes up" message. [This question and answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1081522) suggest that I need to free up some space on my drive; .

So I do as the answer suggests and go into recovery mode, then "Drop to root shell prompt". Then I navigate my way to my own home directory, thinking I'll delete a bunch of audio files which I have backed up elsewhere. But my home directory contains only two files; "Access-Your-Private-Data.desktop" and "README.txt". This is presumably because my home directory is encrypted, I selected that option when I installed Ubuntu.

The read me file informs me that the directory has been unmounted to protect my data. It says to run 'ecryptfs-mount-private". So I try that and I get the message

> ERROR: Encrypted private directory is not setup properly.

Any ideas of how to proceed? I have also tried using [apt](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/apt.8.html) to uninstall packages; I uninstalled Chrome and LibreOffice that way and freed up a few hundred megabytes but I'm still unable to start up.

I've got a 500 GB SSD. I don't remember the details but I was advised to choose some non-standard installation options when I fitted it.

Edit. Here's the results of df.

[image]

Comment: Some other thread "suggesting" that free space might be the issue seems inconclusive. Use the `df` command to make sure.

Comment: Yes, I checked that, it shows /dev/sda1 with 0 available and 100% use. Though  the number of used 1k blocks doesn't look like 100%. I'll edit the question to show the result.