# Ubuntu 18.04 not booting "hold until boot process finishes up"

Tags: boot, 18.04, snap, reboot

When I am booting the computer the following message shows up and is stuck on it:

[image: Started Hold until boot process finishes up]

I already tried to restart the computer with the recovery mode and cleaning up some space. I also tried to move the mouse when starting it that enough entropy is available. I also waited more than an hour to see if it might start on its own. I did not do any upgrades in the past few days and the computer worked perfectly fine yesterday.

The problem could be related to snap. I tried following these threads: [Long boot delay on Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1051762/long-boot-delay-on-ubuntu-loading-splash-screen-following-regular-dist-upgrade-o) and [Boot freezes at start](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1065094/18-04-boot-freezes-at-started-hold-until-boot-process-finishes-up)

My configuration: snap version 2.44.3 and kernel version 5.3.0-51-generic.

Does anyone know what I can do?

Thank you!