# Cannot boot Ubuntu (failed to start mysql community server)

Tags: boot, services, boot-repair

I could not boot my Ubuntu today (the version is 18.04). It shows:

```
[OK] Started hold until boot process finishes up.
[Failed] Failed to start mysql community server.
See 'systemctl status mysql.service' for details.

Started bpfilter
...
```

By the way, my computer is not using a NVIDIA GPU. It's just an Intel integrated graphics card.

Can anyone help? I don't want to reinstall my computer.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.  You haven't given us much, we don't know your release of Ubuntu, nor what messages you got when you entered the command it provided to get details, these details should be added to your question.

Comment: Thanks. I added the ubuntu version. But I did not enter any commands. My computer got freezed when I open it this morning. So I try to restart it, but it cannot finish booting, getting stuck at the error I listed above.

Comment: It get stuck at bpfilter, but that does not seem to be the problem. I opened mysql.conf file and comment the start mysql command in recovery mode, but it doesn't work. Still the same error.

Comment: If you can't use the text terminal (ctrl+alt+F4 for example) I would reboot cleanly (never power-off, but sysrq keys to close fs & reboot), boot a 'live' system (eg. Ubuntu install media; be aware some versions of 'server' do not include 'live' functionality) and `fsck` your system  (I would check hardware health too), then explore from there. The systemd (systemctl) details are harder to see, but maybe `dmesg` or other logs contain clues. More messages before the last may have provided more clues too.

Comment: See [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033613/start-job-is-running-for-hold-until-boot-process-finishes-up-18-04). This can sometimes happen because your disk is completely out of space.

Comment: But I have more than 100 GB disk space.