# Ubuntu 18.04 stuck at splash/grub screen even after boot-repair

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi, bootloader, boot-repair

I'm facing a problem booting my Ubuntu 18.04. So i made a bootable USB-stick(with Ubuntu 18.04) then i booted through 'try Ubuntu', i opened the terminal and gave the following commands:

```
sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/boot/efi
sudo mount -o bind /dev /mnt/dev
sudo mount --rbind /sys /mnt/sys
sudo mount -t proc /proc /mnt/proc
sudo chroot /mnt /bin/bash
add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
apt-get update
apt-get install -y boot-repair
boot-repair
```

i couldn't run the last command as root due to xhost, Display errors so i typed exit and gave the last four commands again. Here is the boot-repair result:
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/4cMHnxqkRC/

After boot-repair i rebooted but i am still stuck at splash screen, here is a foto [open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3tCAQ.jpg).

When doing a `sudo fdisk -l` i get this information:

```
Device       Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1     2048    1050623    1048576  512M EFI System
/dev/sda2  1050624 1953523711 1952473088  931G Linux filesystem


Device     Boot Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1  *     2512 30926847 30924336 14.8G  b W95 FAT32
```

I don't know what is wrong and how to fix the problem. I hope somebody can help me.

Comment: Your grub is working fine, post grub splash screen indicates some other issue boot repair does not fix the issue you are trying to fix.

Comment: Are you getting grub menu? And then boot recovery mode? What video card/chip?

Comment: @oldfred yes with three options ubuntu/advanced.../system setup. when i choose the first option i get stuck and the same when booting in recovery mode. I have Intel Corporation Skylake GT2 [HD Graphics 520] video card.

Comment: Recovery mode should show boot process. Often issue not last line shown, but several lines above will show an error or issue. From recovery mode, can you turn on Internet & run update from terminal?

Answer (score 0):

Your bootloader is fine maybe your disk is full try up freeing some space on your drive

Its worth to try out the solutions listed in this thread.

Source: [Start job is running for hold until boot process finishes up 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033613/start-job-is-running-for-hold-until-boot-process-finishes-up-18-04)

Comment: thank u for trying to help me. According to Gparted, i have  772GiB unused space on sda2 and 494MiB unused space on sda1. Do u think i still should try to free some space?

Comment: @aghiad No worries, maybe try this solution  https://askubuntu.com/a/1080551/1198244 also try unplugging all usb devices and rebooting

Comment: so in tty i gave the `efibootmgr` command and this was the resut: bootCurrent:0000,timeout:0, bootOrder: 0000, 3000, 0001, 2001, 2002, 2004   whereby Boot0000* ubuntu, Boot0001* debian, Boot2001* EFI USB Device, Boot2002* EFI DVD/CDROM, Boot3000* Internal Hard Disk or solid state disk. then i run `sudo efibootmgr -b 2001 -B` and rebooted but i still have the same problem