# Internal laptop screen stuck on Ubuntu loading screen, secondary monitor working just fine. (Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: drivers, 18.04, nvidia, kernel, multiple-monitors

I have a laptop with a gtx 1060 currently running on NVIDIA's 418.39 driver. My secondary screen is working just fine, but my laptop screen is just stuck on the loading Ubuntu screen with the 5 dots.

If i do a `sudo prime-select intel` and `reboot`my laptop screen works just fine but is stuck in 800x600 resolution without me being able to change it. when I do `sudo prime-select nvidia` I am stuck in the situation explained.

I have spend so much time trying to fix this, I am at a loss now, hopefully someone here can point me in the right direction. It would be nice to be able to use my laptop without a secondary screen.

Update: After trying to fix this issue my laptop screen now dosen't work at all when loading Ubuntu, I have never been able to successfully install the Nvidia drivers either.

Comment: Try the Nvidia `396` or older driver. If you provide your laptop make and model number others with the same platform might know the solution.

Comment: Also with no external monitor attached can you boot into BIOS and change settings? If yes can you boot with Live USB with no external monitor attached?

Comment: I have tried almost every nvidia driver version 3xx and 4xx available, the issue started when trying to install cudnn and cuda. I can boot with a live USB no problem, and that works just fine. I have grub with windows installed that also works just fine.

This is the PC: https://www.excaliberpc.com/689344/msi-p65-creator-8re-020-sliver.html

Answer (score 1):

I did not have this issue myself, but here is an educated guess, informed by other cases of "stuck on the loading Ubuntu screen with the 5 dots":

The display manager (which should display the login screen) cannot start until the graphical "loading Ubuntu" screen has finished, which seems to not happen for your internal display. Since that graphical "loading Ubuntu" screen does not necessarily display on all available screens, that could be the reason why your external screen is unaffected.

A good indicator of this cause for the problem is when you have the following message in `/var/log/boot.log`:

```
A start job is running for Hold until boot process finishes up (Xmin Xs/no limit)
```

The graphical "loading Ubuntu" screen is called `plymouth`, and it is not essential at all. When it is not installed, a text-mode screen will show the five dots instead. So the following may already fix your issue:

```
sudo apt remove plymouth
```

And then reboot. For variants of this solution, some specifically from people with Nvidia driver issues, see [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/760825).

Comment: I get the following error trying to run remove plymouth:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libglx-mesa0 : Depends: libglapi-mesa (= 18.2.2-0ubuntu1~18.04.2) but 18.2.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.2 is to be installed
                Breaks: libglx-mesa0:i386 (!= 18.2.2-0ubuntu1~18.04.2) but 18.2.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.2 is to be installed

When trying to follow the instructions given in the error message and through some googling I get this error: E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: I am starting to think that the only solution to this problem is reinstalling my computer

Answer (score 0):

> EDID error?

It may be that the Ubuntu drivers are not detecting your screen correctly, and will only run at standard vesa settings.

How I solve this - Is to go into windows and pull the EDID.BIN with CRU.

you can get custom Resolution Utility here...

> https://www.monitortests.com/forum/Thread-Custom-Resolution-Utility-CRU

Then point to it with instructions...

> http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/alt-nvidia-304-xconfig.1.html