# Change language in Ubuntu tty2 login mode

Tags: login, tty, system-language

I have login problem of this kind:

[A start job is running for Hold until boot process finishes up (Xmin Xs/no limit)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760825/cannot-boot-system-due-to-start-job-running-for-hold/761363#761363)

Do when I press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, so it going to login page and the problem is that I can not change language from Persian to English to insert my user and pass.

I already I changing the language at Ubuntu by pressing the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>, but it doesn't work here.

So how can I change the language in this mode?

***Update:***
I have this problem in advance boot option (safe mode), grub ...

I also tried to switch language by holding  (if I remember correctly) "the <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>2</kbd> at numpad" to type English yes at dpkg repair option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you have configured your system locale incorrectly.

Using the next command we could get list of available locales:

```
locale -a
```

In my case I have:

```
C
C.UTF-8
en_AG
en_AG.utf8
en_AU.utf8
en_BW.utf8
en_CA.utf8
en_DK.utf8
en_GB.utf8
en_HK.utf8
en_IE.utf8
en_IL
en_IL.utf8
en_IN
en_IN.utf8
en_NG
en_NG.utf8
en_NZ.utf8
en_PH.utf8
en_SG.utf8
en_US.utf8
en_ZA.utf8
en_ZM
en_ZM.utf8
en_ZW.utf8
POSIX
uk_UA.utf8
```

To get your current locales configuration run `locale`:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=uk_UA.UTF-8
LC_TIME=uk_UA.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=uk_UA.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=uk_UA.UTF-8
LC_NAME=uk_UA.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=uk_UA.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=uk_UA.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=uk_UA.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=uk_UA.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

Login as root in your gui terminal, where you could change to English and do:

```
update-locale LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 && . /etc/default/locale
```

Make sure, you have `us` the first keyboard layout in `/etc/default/keyboard`

```
$ cat /etc/default/keyboard 
XKBLAYOUT=us,ua,ru
XKBVARIANT=,winkeys,
BACKSPACE=guess
```

If `us` not the first keyboard layout, make it the first and execute:

```
. /etc/default/keyboard
```

Also, try `update-grub2` and `update-initramfs -u` after previous commands using.

**If you could not get into your system because of wrong locales configuration, then**

- boot from Live CD (Try without installing option in Ubuntu installation image)
- identify your root partition by `sudo fdisk -l`
- mount your root partition in read/write mode
- configure `/etc/default/keyboard` file as said previously
- add into `/etc/bash.bashrc` the next at the end:

  ```
  export LC_ALL= "en_US.UTF-8"
  export LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
  export LANGUAGE = "en_US.UTF-8"
  ```
- try to boot into your system

Comment: But I can not login to access the terminal, now what must I do? It must be something in grub boot editing, am I right?

Comment: it have because of 100% used space of home drive of Ubuntu and  i have many things like removing the NVIDIA drivers and ... but the language problem solved by this setting by this kind: http://shorturl.at/dhwE6

Answer (score 0):

The stupid way of solving it that helped me (thanks Gryu):

1. Login to tty using Alt + numpad code ([A-Z] is 65 to 90, and [a-z] is 97 to 122)
2. The same way type sudo nano /etc/default/keyboard (code blocks below are numpad code sequences):

   `115 117 100 111 (spacebar) 110 97 110 111 (spacebar)`

   `47 101 (tab) 100 101 102 97 (tab) 107 101 (tab) (enter)`
3. Using arrows, navigate to XKBLAYOUT line and add "us," (`117 115 44`) after =
4. Quit nano and save file: `024 121 (enter)`
5. Reboot: `114 101 98 111 111 116 (enter)`

May be helpful for someone :)