# Ubuntu 19.10 keeps stuck on loading screen

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 19.10

I have a ThinkPad T450 and installed Ubuntu 19.10 on it, along with a grub boot loader. Sometimes when I try to boot it, it keeps stuck on the loading screen, other times it works just fine.

I already found [this article](https://itsfoss.com/fix-ubuntu-freezing/) describing my problem and providing a solution. I tried adding `nomodeset` to the grub command and it booted, but it took about ten times as long to boot as it takes when the flag is not set.

Also, this article puts having a NVIDIA graphics card as the reason, sonce the driver may be incompatible with Linux. However, my ThinkPad only got a Intel Graphics Card, so the drivers should all work fine.

So what may be the reason why I get this problem? And why does it only occurr sometimes, but other times it boots just fine? And most importantly, how can I fix this?

**Edit**:
This is the logging output when the boot gets stuck. [image]

In the config file `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf` I set `WaylandEnable=false`, otherwise I couldn't get the logging to show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying some solutions provided on [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760825/cannot-boot-system-due-to-start-job-running-for-hold), the one that finally worked was just removing plymouth:

`sudo apt remove plymouth`

Now it doesen't show a loading screen at all when booting, but I've rebootet several times and it did not get stuck a single time.

I still kept Wayland disabled like heynnema suggested.